# Optimization of total ordering in Alloy and Kodkod

Tags: alloy

It is said in various places (e.g. here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587180/is-using-util-ordering-exactly-the-same-as-axiomatizing-a-total-order-in-the-usu) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308778/the-util-ordering-module-and-ordered-subsignatures/17326033#17326033)) that the total ordering relation is hardwired in order to improve the efficiency of analyses (and to get atom names to appear in the "natural" order).

As far as I understand, the optimization is made in Kodkod ([in this piece of code](https://github.com/emina/kodkod/blob/a0c724011a8ad303dd19125007511072899b771e/src/kodkod/engine/fol2sat/SymmetryBreaker.java#L385)). However, is there an article or document explaining in more detail (than the Java documentation, which speaks in terms of Boolean matrices and does not provide an argumentation for the algorithm --which is fine in source code documentation--) the optimizations made in Kodkod? As far as I can tell, E. Torlak's PhD thesis does not speak of these ones (a paper by I. Shlyakhter speak about other optimizations, but I don't know whether those are implemented in Kodkod or Alloy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This optimization is made in Kodkod, at the code location you found.  It is described briefly in [Ilya Shlyakhter's PhD thesis](http://people.csail.mit.edu/ilya_shl/thesis/thesis.ps) (p. 111, Section 4.5.5).